# How can I listen to user voice input without starting a new Activity

Tags: google-glass

I have an activity, and I'd like to listen for additional user input without having to navigate to the voice activity.

Basically I'm showing a card scroll list of options, and I want the user to say "navigate" to navigate to the location rather than tapping it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, contextual navigation is not allowed in Glass. There is already an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273) in place for this.